# Boost Python quickstart examples give error

Tags: python, boost, python-3.x, boost-python

when i try running the example under C:\boost_1_50_0\libs\python\example\quickstart i get the following error and my python file gets removed ( which is quite annoying ) . I am using Python 3.3 & Boost 1.50 on a Windows 7 OS .

C:\boost_1_50_0\libs\python\example\quickstart>bjam toolset=msvc --verbose-test
test > error_log

error_log:

```
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1662 targets...
...updating 11 targets...
copy test_extending.py
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

    copy /b  + this-file-does-not-exist-A698EE7806899E69 "test_extending.py" "bin\test_ext.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\test_extending.py"

...failed copy test_extending.py bin\test_ext.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\test_extending.py...
...removing test_extending.py
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.obj
extending.cpp
msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pyd
   Creating library bin\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.lib and object bin\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.exp
msvc.manifest.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pyd
...skipped <pbin\test_ext.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>test_ext for lack of <pbin\test_ext.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>test_extending.py...
msvc.link bin\test_embed.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.exe
LINK : warning LNK4001: no object files specified; libraries used
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
bin\test_embed.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /subsystem:console /out:"bin\test_embed.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.exe" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python33\libs"  @"bin\test_embed.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.exe.rsp"
        if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

...failed msvc.link bin\test_embed.test\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\test_embed.exe
```

So there are 2 errors here that need to be fixed :

a ) copy test_extending.py
    The syntax of the command is incorrect.

b ) LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup

Any ideas how do i fix this ?

Comment: So, did you fixed item b)?

Comment: No sorry i could never get it to work .. I hope that you add the solution here in case you are able to solve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is with a). Problem b) appears to be a bug in the boost example, the jam file is trying to make a test executable from an executable instead of a static lib or cpp file.

I [documented what I had to do](https://gist.github.com/teeks99/bb4921dffc8a74423c26#file-boost-python-quickstart-md) to get the embed example running.